# Docker Swarm set which service goes to which machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Docker Swarm set which service goes to which machine.

Is there any way to set which service or service replicas goes to which worker machine ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [placement section](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#placement) of the compose file, you can specify [constraints](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#specify-service-constraints---constraint). I'd recommend using node labels so you can add more potential nodes (should an existing node fail) without redefining any deployments bound to a node, but you can also specify hostnames. The result looks like:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - "node.hostname==dbhost"
```